# What is the difference between split, multline, align, breqn for breaking an equation into multiple lines?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, breqn, multline

Sorry, if this question sounds a bit amateurish, but I haven't been able to find a good summary about the differences between these four environments for multi-lining an equation. Where do they differ and which one should I choose under different circumstances?

Comment: For an excellent summary of what the `split`, `multline`, and `align` environments do, I recommend reading section 3, "Displayed equations", of the user guide of the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math) package. It may be loaded by typing `texdoc amsmath` at a command prompt. Similarly, to bring up the user guide of the `breqn` package, type `texdoc breqn` at a command prompt.

Comment: Also `texdoc mathmode` is a good source.

Comment: The link of the first comment is broken.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As noted in comments the `amsmath` and `breqn` documentation have several good examples, also the `mathtools` package has extended versions of several of the `amsmath` alignments. But the usual style here is to answer inline rather than refer to manuals, so this is a document giving the basic usage of the environments you mention.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

Align, from amsmath package:
numbered equations aligned at points marked
with \verb|&| usually just before a relation.
\begin{align}
a_1& =b_1+c_1\\
a_2& =b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
\end{align}

split, also from amsmath,
similar alignment to align, but the whole construct fits within
equation (or other display math) and is numbered as a unit.
\begin{equation}\label{xx}
\begin{split}
a& =b+c-d\\
 & \quad +e-f\\
 & =g+h\\
 & =i
\end{split}
\end{equation}

multline, from amsmath
for lonq expressions taking more than one line,
with no specifed alignment points.
\begin{multline}
a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+\\
l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+w+x+y+z
\end{multline}


breqn is not part of the amsmath collection and is a highly experimental
package that tries to automate the line breaking.
Here it automatically spots the relations and adds
the line breaks and alignment points.
It also automatically handles the trailing full stop after the display.
\begin{dmath}
T(n) \hiderel{\leq} T(2^{\lceil\lg n\rceil})
  \leq c(3^{\lceil\lg n\rceil}
    -2^{\lceil\lg n\rceil})
  <3c\cdot3^{\lg n}
  =3c\,n^{\lg3}
\end{dmath}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: How you solve the same problem with parenthesis like \left[ and \right]?

Comment: @AlejandroSazo ? sorry I can't guess what problem you mean. Perhaps you should ask a question on the site.

Comment: Sorry I just found that there is no problem with left and right parenthesis while breaking an equation.

Comment: is \quad convential use in this case to align the content on the right hand side of the equal sign?

Comment: @Xaser no, perhaps I should have used `\qquad` the apparent alignment there was accidental and unintended

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. If you say that \qquad may have been better, what are the conventions on the indentation of the second line (where not new = is involved)?

Comment: @Xaser I don't know of any formal convention but the styles are normally to just wrap so not indented at all, but if you choose to indent it's better if it's obviously indented and not looking like it's aligned with something. `\quad` and `\qquad` are available for that use but I wouldn't say theer are really any conventions.

Comment: @Xaser, here some notes about spacing in math mode: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode. I wanted to align a letter `n` (not a `+`), and what worked for me was something like `&\quad\;`. `\quad` for the space of the `= ` that I am not putting in that line, and `\;` for the standard space after the `=` operator.

Comment: wouldnt the obvious alignment be a = & b+c-d\\& +e-f\\ = & g+h\\ = & i ?

Comment: @peter if you want to align after the = rather than before you need `={}&` to get the correct relation spacing.

Comment: yes, i forgot. is there a reason for this or could we maybe just redefine & so its rel-friendly from both sides?