# I am not sure why this is not lining up? My errors say "Missing } inserted?" Not really sure where this is occuring

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

```
\begin{align*}
 |S_n(x)-S_n(y)| &= |\Sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x)^{n} -\Sum_{k=0}^n a_k(y)^{n}| \\
 &= |\Sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x^{n}*y^{n})| \\
&\le \Sum_{k=0}^n$ $|a_k(x^{n}*y^{n})| \\
&=  \Sum_{k=0}^n |a_k(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}*y + ...+ x*y^{n-2}+ y^{n-1})| \\
&\le \Sum_{k=0}^n |a_k(x-y)(L^{n-1}+L^{n-2}*L + ...+ L*L^{n-2}+ L^{n-1})| \\
&= \Sum_{k=0}^n |a_k(x-y)(n*L^{n-1})| \\
&< \Sum_{k=0}^n |a_k*\delta*(n*L^{n-1})| \\
&\le \delta\Sum_{k=0}^n |a_k||(n*L^{n-1})| \\
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two mistakes in your code:

- `\sum` starts with a lower-case "s"
- there is a pair of dollar signs `$ $` that makes an error.

Other things to improve your code (thanks to the guys in the comments):

- use `\dots` (probably standard, the dots are then centered) or `\ldots` (if you prefer baseline dots) instead of typing "..."
- replace the "*" by `\cdot`, or even better leave out most of them
- you might want to enlarge the enclosing "|" pairs. It did that here with `\Bigg` and `\big` commands, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38870/103046) for more details
- you don't need a line-break `\\` at the end of the last line
- the `align*` environment works for the example. But you should also consider the `split` environment. See for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239309/103046) for details.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
    |S_n(x)-S_n(y)| &= \Bigg|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x)^{n} -\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(y)^{n}\Bigg| \\
    &= \Bigg|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x^{n}\cdot y^{n})\Bigg| \\
    &\le \sum_{k=0}^n \big|a_k(x^{n}\cdot y^{n})\big| \\
    &=  \sum_{k=0}^n \big|a_k(x-y)\big(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\cdot y + \dots + x\cdot y^{n-2}+ y^{n-1}\big)\big| \\
    &\le \sum_{k=0}^n \big|a_k(x-y)\big(L^{n-1}+L^{n-2}\cdot L + \dots + L\cdot L^{n-2}+ L^{n-1}\big)\big| \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^n \big|a_k(x-y)\big(n\cdot L^{n-1}\big)\big| \\
    &< \sum_{k=0}^n \big|a_k\cdot \delta\cdot \big(n\cdot L^{n-1}\big)\big| \\
    &\le \delta\cdot\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|\cdot\big|\big(n\cdot L^{n-1}\big)\big|
\end{split}\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `+ \ldots +` is wrong: use `+ \dots +` instead.

Comment: Why is `\ldots` wrong?

Comment: The dots between two `+` signs should be centered.  In any case, it’s almost always best to use `\dots` and let the `amsmath` package decide how to position the dots.

Comment: I like my dots to be on the baseline. According to a quick search on Wikipedia, this is perfectly fine in German and Russian, but non-standard in English. Anyway, my answer already points out that `\dots`is a valid choice for this case.

Comment: Fair enough: perhaps the terseness of my comment was a bit rude, and I apologize for that.  Nonetheless, I’d maintain the point that, in general, it’s best to recommend using `\dots`.  Allow me to draw your attention to a few other slips that I’ve just noticed in your answer: (1) there should be no `\\ ` after the last line of the `align*` environment; (2) perhaps (I say perhaps) it would be better to use `split` here; (3) vertical bars should indeed made larger in some places; (4) in the last line, I really think that `\delta\cdot\sum...` is better.

Comment: No offense taken. `split` is indeed a better choice if one wants to have a number for the equation. I'll update my answer with your comments.

Comment: AMS provides the \dotsb command for dots between binary operators.  By default, it's centered.