# equation: Write equal sign below each other

Tags: equations

I want to write the equal sign below each other. My code is

```
\begin{equation*}
\overline{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}
=\frac{1}{3}(1 + 2 + 3)
=2
\end{equation*}
```

Now i' get

[image]

but it should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the package `amsmath` and use the `{align}` environment:

```
\begin{align*}
\overline{x}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} \\
&=\frac{1}{3}(1 + 2 + 3) \\
&=2
\end{align*}
```

End all lines except the last one with `\\` and insert `&` before the symbol you want the columns to be aligned at.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `split`?

Comment: Nope, but i found this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239252/what-is-the-difference-between-split-multline-align-breqn-for-breakin  I will read about this topic. But for now, ``amsmath`` and ``align`` is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\overline{x} &=& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\\
&=& \frac{1}{3}(1 + 2 + 3)\\
&=& 2
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks very much for your first contribution! =) However, you should know that `eqnarray` is severely deprecated and out of date; you should definitely consider following the accepted answer and switch to `align`