# spacing around equality sign with {split}, {align}

Tags: align, split

In a long equation, I'd like to add a line break such that the equality sign (and only that) on the next line is outdented. 
(Quite a typical typesetting I think.) I tried `split`, but that gives a way too narrow spacing right of the equal sign. `align` behaves just the same way.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 &abc\\
=&def\\
 &+ijk
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0K3W.png)

Perhaps a different alignment/environment should be used here. Any hints?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Maybe `&=` and then `&\quad+` for the continuation line.

Comment: You can keep the `=` symbol to the left and have better spacing with `={}&` rather than just `=&`. It looks a bit odd to me, though.

Comment: all ams alignments are designed to be used as `&=` not `=&` although as Ian says, you can use `={}&` if you really want the alignment to the right of the =

Comment: `={}&` looks fine indeed, feel free to bump this to an answer. What's a more common way of typesetting those lines though?

Comment: It probably massively depends on what you're formatting and why, but I might be inclined to use multline for this. Hoewver, to get literally what you want, I would use `={}&` as others suggest. Some alignment options are here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239252/what-is-the-difference-between-split-multline-align-breqn-for-breakin

Comment: @rbrignall -- I'd be inclined to use `multlined` (requires `mathtools`) rather than `multline`, as the latter spreads the lines across the full text width.  It's possible to "corral" them, but it's a pain.