# newline with `\\` does not work

Tags: line-breaking, math-operators

to compile Tex, I use latex/pdftex version of `LaTex`. Here are some details

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```

My problem is, if I want a newline in either `\begin{equation}` or `$$`, the operator `\\` does not work. How do I sperate lines? In other forms of `Tex`, the `\\` seperates the lines of such as

```
$$
<expression1> \\ <expression2>
$$
```

It should seperate in two lines but it does not.

Comment: `\\ ` should not make a newline in `equation` which is a single line equation environment. Use `align` or `gather` from `amsmath` package for multi-line equations.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239309/1090

Comment: thanks for the info! very helpful, I was just browsing https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations and sure amsmath package is helpful.

Comment: note that `$$` should not be used in latex at all, independent of `\\ ` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\`  should not make a newline in `equation` which is a single line equation environment, or in `$$` (but `$$` should never be used in LaTeX anyway).

Use `align` or `gather` from the `amsmath` package for multi-line equations.