# Error: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. in 'multline' environment

Tags: equations, errors, align

I can't see where the issue in the following script, would anyone help please?

```
\begin{multline}
    a\left[ r^2 \sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1} \tilde{{d}^{(2)}_{i\ell}} \phi_{\ell jk} + s^2  \sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1} \tilde{{d}^{(2)}_{j\ell}} \phi_{j\ell}  \right] + b\left[ t^2 \sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1} \tilde{{d}^{(2)}_{k\ell}} \phi_{ij\ell}  \right] + a \left[r^2\left(  d^{(2)}_{i0} \phi_{0jk}+  d^{(2)}_{iN} \phi_{Njk}\right) + s^2 \left(  d^{(2)}_{j0} \phi_{i0k}+  d^{(2)}_{jN} \phi_{iNk}   \right)        \right] &+ b \left[ t^2 \left( d^{(2)}_{k0} \phi_{ij0} + d^{(2)}_{kN} \phi_{ijN} \right) \right]  = 
     \frac{\textbf{S}_{ijk}}{n_{ijk}}-\frac{a n^x_{ijk}}{n_{ijk}}\left[r\sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1}\tilde{d}_{i\ell}^{(1)} \phi_{\ell jk} \right] - \frac{a n^y_{ijk}}{n_{ijk}} \left[s\sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1}\tilde{d}_{j\ell}^{(1)} \phi_{i\ell k} \right] - \frac{b n^z_{ijk}}{n_{ijk}} \left[ t \sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1}\tilde{d}_{k\ell}^{(1)} \phi_{ij\ell} \right] \\ -  \frac{a r n^x_{ijk}}{n_{ijk}} \left(  d^{(1)}_{i0} \phi_{0jk}+  d^{(1)}_{iN} \phi_{Njk} \right) - \frac{a s n^y_{ijk}}{n_{ijk}} \left(  d^{(1)}_{i0} \phi_{0jk}+  d^{(1)}_{iN} \phi_{Njk} \right) - \frac{b t n^z_{ijk}}{ n_{ijk}}  \left(  d^{(1)}_{k0} \phi_{ij0}+  d^{(1)}_{kN} \phi_{ijN}\right) 
\end{multline}
```

I get the error showing in the last line,

```
l.204 \end{multline}
```

Comment: There's an `&`: `...\right] &+ b \left[ t^2....` but `&` can't be used in `multline`. (See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239252/)

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't see the ``&`` for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an `&` on the first line of your code:

`...\right] &+ b \left[ t^2....`

but `&` can't be used in `multline`.

(See also [What is the difference between split, multline, align, breqn for breaking an equation into multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239252/226))