# Aligning equations in columns

Tags: equations, align, alignment

as the title says, i wanna make three aligned colums of equations. First column being aligned left with the text above, second centered and last aligned right with the text.
I am using *align* environment but the alignment doesn't look just right. I am really just a beginner at using LaTeX, so pardon me for trivial questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have three columns in an equation, use groups separated by `&`. You can control if the whole equation environment is centred (`align`) or distributed over the page (`flalign`).

Just in case you would like a non-centred equation, you can also wrap `flalign` inside the `minipage` with calculated mandatory argument *width* and horizontal spacing.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameColor{\color{green}}

 
\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]
\begin{align*}
  \alpha_i &= a_ib_j - \beta_i\gamma_j   &   \gamma_i &=r_i - r_j   &   a &= b + c + d + e\\
  \alpha_j &= c - \beta_j                &   \gamma_j &=r_j - r_k   &   f &= g + h \\
  \alpha_k &= d + \gamma_k               &   \gamma_k &=r_h - r_i   &   i &= j + k + l 
\end{align*}

\kant[2][1]
\begin{flalign*}
  \alpha_i &= a_ib_j - \beta_i\gamma_j   &   \gamma_i &=r_i - r_j   &   a &= b + c + d + e\\
  \alpha_j &= c - \beta_j                &   \gamma_j &=r_j - r_k   &   f &= g + h \\
  \alpha_k &= d + \gamma_k               &   \gamma_k &=r_h - r_i   &   i &= j + k + l 
\end{flalign*}  

\kant[3][1]
\par\noindent\hspace{60pt}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-70pt} % 60pt+10pt (left+right margin)
  \begin{flalign*}
    \alpha_i &= a_ib_j - \beta_i\gamma_j   &   \gamma_i &=r_i - r_j   &   a &= b + c + d + e\\
    \alpha_j &= c - \beta_j                &   \gamma_j &=r_j - r_k   &   f &= g + h \\
    \alpha_k &= d + \gamma_k               &   \gamma_k &=r_h - r_i   &   i &= j + k + l 
  \end{flalign*}  
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

% See also https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath,
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239252, and
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782.

\begin{multline} % Remark: "multline" is written without an "i" after "mult".
p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\ 
- 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3\\
- 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{multline}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]